# android toolbar disappeares when I open dialog or switch between apps

Tags: java, android, image, android-toolbar, android-camera-intent

I have an android app, in which I made a parent activity (let's say "BaseActivity") that all activities extend from that.
In "BaseActivity", I made a toolbar with some images, like this:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, binding.getRoot(), false);
        toolbar.addView(view);
```

It works ok until I use a fragmentdialog (usually this fragment takes some photos) or switch between apps (for example after making call)

[while it works ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6nLd.jpg)

[after switching app or opening dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kToBx.jpg)
Still other part of app work as I expected.

I need your advice :)